# Why does function return None under certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote brackets check function using stack. Seems like it works, but when i put, for example '(((([]){}' as parameter (few repeatable symbols at the beginning) it returns None. I think its linked with stack len but still didnt figure it out

```
def func(brakets):
    stack = []
    for char in brakets:
        if char in '([{':
            stack.append(char)
           # print(stack)
        if len(stack) == 0:
            return False
        opener = stack.pop()

        if opener == '(' and char != ')':
            return False
        if opener == '[' and char != ']':
            return False
        if opener == '{' and char != '}':
            return False
    if not stack:
        return True
```

After some refactoring I did this:

```
def func(pattern):
    stack = []

    for bracket in pattern:
        if bracket in dct.keys():
            stack.append(bracket)
            print(stack)
        elif bracket in dct.values():
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return False
            opened_bracket = stack.pop()
            if dct[opened_bracket] != bracket:
                return False

    if not stack:
        return True
```

But still the same problem

```
def func(pattern):
    stack = []

    for bracket in pattern:
        if bracket in dct.keys():
            stack.append(bracket)
            print(stack)
        elif bracket in dct.values():
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return False
            opened_bracket = stack.pop()
            if dct[opened_bracket] != bracket:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    if not stack:
        return True
```

and still None. But after the loop ends with none of conditions completed I put else statement

Comment: And what happens if the stack is not empty when the function ends?

Comment: All your `return` statements are within `if` conditions. If none of those match, there's no explicit return value…

Comment: I also think you do too many unnecessary checks. Just do if char in brackets or something like that.

Comment: You probably meant `return not stack` instead of `if not stack: return True`

Comment: Hint: you always `append` to the stack, and immediately afterwards `pop` the same value again. That can't be right…

Comment: Isn't the following sufficient? :`def fun(brackets): if '(' in brackets or '[' in brackets or '{' in brackets: return True; return False`

Comment: @Blue If you change the definition of what the function is supposed to do… (And we can only guess that this is supposed to check the symmetry of nested brackets.)

Comment: I've got some help with refactoring but still the same problem:

Comment: Again, what happens after the loop if the stack is non-empty? What does the function return?

Answer (score 0):

There are three different kinds of mismatches you can run into:

1. We see a closing character (')', ']' or '}'), so we would like to
   pop from the stack, but the stack is empty. This means that you have
   an unmatched closing character.
2. We see a closing character, so we would like to pop from the stack.
   The stack is not empty, but the opening character we popped does not
   match the current closing character (e.g. the last opening character
   we pushed onto the stack was a '(', but the current closing
   character is ']')
3. After looking at every single character (after the loop), the stack
   should be empty (for every opening character we pushed onto the
   stack, we should have had one matching closing character to pop it
   off the stack). If the stack is not empty after the loop, this means
   we have one or more opening characters with no matching closing
   character.

In the code I posted below, instead of pushing individual characters onto the stack, the stack is more like a stack of dictionaries (I call them pair types in my code). A given pair type tells you, given an opening char, which closing char you expect to see when popping. This has the advantage of simplifying things in the loop - when checking to see if the most recent opening char matches the current closing char, instead of a chain of if-statements we can just look up what the expected closing char should be. This has the additional advantage that your is_balanced function can be extended later on if you want to add new types of pairs.

```
def is_balanced(string):

    pair_types = [
        {"open": "(", "close": ")"},
        {"open": "[", "close": "]"},
        {"open": "{", "close": "}"}]

    def get_pair_type_from_open_char(open_char):
        try:
            return next(pair_type for pair_type in pair_types if pair_type["open"] == open_char)
        except StopIteration:
            # No such pair exists
            return None

    all_close_chars = "".join([pair_type["close"] for pair_type in pair_types])

    stack = []

    for char in string:
        pair_type = get_pair_type_from_open_char(char)
        if pair_type is not None:
            stack.append(pair_type)
        elif char in all_close_chars:
            # We would like to pop
            try:
                top = stack.pop()
            except IndexError:
                # The stack was empty
                return False
            else:
                # The stack was not empty
                # However, the current open char (top of the stack)...
                # ...needs to match the current close char
                if top["close"] != char:
                    # The current pair of chars are mismatched (e.g. "(" and "]")
                    return False

    # If there are things left over in the stack after the loop...
    # ...this means we have open chars with no matching close chars
    return not stack


def main():

    string = "(())[({})]"

    print("The string is" + [" not", ""][is_balanced(string)] + " balanced")

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```